# ftp_size returns -1 after a file is uploaded using curl

Tags: php, ftp

My script packs some files with ZIP then uploads this ZIP to another server. After the upload it checks size of the ZIP on the FTP and locally. If sizes are the same- the local ZIP is deleted.

The problem is `ftp_size()` returns -1. But only in the real script. In my test script it works fine.

**Test script works like this:**

```
$f = ftp_connect(HOST);
$res = ftp_login($f, USER, PASS); 
$fname = 'archive_2018-09-18_13-39';
$fsize = ftp_size($f, "$fname-img.zip").''; 
$fsize2 = filesize("backup/$fname-img.zip").''; 
echo $fsize . '<br>' . $fsize2;
```

and it returns:

```
22907946995
22907946995
```

**The real script works like this:**

```
$f = ftp_connect(HOST);
$res = ftp_login($f, USER, PASS); 
$fname = 'archive_' . date('Y-m-d_H-i');

exec("zip -r -0 backup/$fname-img.zip  \"website\" 2>&1");
exec('curl -T "' . "backup/$fname-img.zip" . '" ftp://' . HOST . ' --user ' . USER . ':' . PASS . ' 2>&1');

$fsize = ftp_size($f, "$fname-img.zip").''; 
$fsize2 = filesize("backup/$fname-img.zip").''; 
echo $fsize . '<br>' . $fsize2;
```

and it shows:

```
-1
22907946995
```

Real script uploads file just fine. It just doesn't show correct size on the FTP server.
So it's not a problem with size of the file and not a problem with FTP connection.

Comment: Why not use `ftp_put()` to upload the file? Oh, and -1 probably just means the file, in the checked directory, doesn't exist.

Comment: If you get `-1`, try and call [error_get_last()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) and log it to check if that gives you any clues.

Comment: Your title says *"sometimes"*. While from your question text, it seems that you get -1 always (*in the real script*). Please elaborate on this.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson error_get_last()  returned nothing but I still got -1.

Comment: Do you have an access to FTP server log file? Can you post it? Or can do a wireshark capture of the FTP session?

Comment: What if you move `ftp_connect` only after `exec`? Why do you even call curl to upload the file, instead of using PHP `ftp_put`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I don't have access to FTP log. I can't even log there from anything other than my main server. FTP server is owned by the same company as my main server and they only allow connection from their machines. I don't trust PHP with uploading 22 GB files so I use curl for uploads. I mean ftp_put certainly won't do the job well. I'd have to write tons of code to handle exceptions, errors, time limits and such.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I just moved ftp_connect after exec. The script needs about 30 minutes so I'll know if this helped in 30 minutes.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It actually worked. Thank you! I moved ftp_connect after exec and now size is returned correctly. Perhaps you could post this as an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `ftp_connect` only after the call to `curl`. There is possibly some caching involved that prevents the FTP server from returning correct size immediately, if the file is uploaded using a different connection.

---

Though I'd strongly suggest you to use PHP functions to upload the file.